# Send messages using Microsoft Graph API from a specific account

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api

I want to send email from a specific account (different from the one I'm logged in with). Can anyone tell me how can I authenticate that account to have execute permission on it (with Javascript)? I'm not creating the message on the account I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using **delegated permissions**, you can only send emails on behalf of other users who have grated mailbox access to the signed in user.

If you need to send email as any user, you will need to use **application permissions** with a flow like [Client Credentials Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow), but this means your app must live on a secure server side environment.

If you need to send mail on behalf of some users other than the signed in user then you can have them delegated or share their mailbox with the signed in user.

Check this SO thread - [Microsoft Graph API - Sending email as another user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52647670/microsoft-graph-api-sending-email-as-another-user)